# Put full XML file to list

Tags: c#, xml

```
  <Clients>
  <Client Id="1">
    <Name>Granicentro</Name>
    <Adresses>
      <Adress Name="">
        <Ip>111,111,111,111</Ip>
        <Port>1111</Porta>
      </Adress>
      <Adress Name="2222">
        <Ip>222,222,222,222</Ip>
        <Port>2222</Porta>
      </Adress>
      <Adress Name="3333">
        <Ip>333,333,333,333</Ip>
        <Port>3333</Porta>
      </Adress>
    </Adresses>
  </Client>
</Clients>
```

I have this XML document. How do I get a list of all clients/addresses?

I have tried this without success(no exception, just no data to show):

```
IEnumerable<string> adds= from client in XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Clients.xml")
  .Descendants("Adresses")
   where((string)cliente.Element("Name") == cliente)
   select cliente.Element("Ip").Value;
```

What is the proper way to add all the XML file to a list of this sort?:

```
class Client
{
    public string ClientName{ get; set; }
    public List<Adress> Adresses{ get; set; }
}

class Adress
{
    public string AdressName{ get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public int port{ get; set; }
}

List<Client> clientes = new List<Client>();
```

**Complete, and Verifiable example:**
I just need the data from the XML file to manipulate at runtime.
Right now I have this query to get the name of the clients:

```
            IEnumerable<string> names = from client in XDocument.Load(@"D:\W\Clients.xml")
                                                         .Descendants("client")
                                    orderby client.Element("Id") descending
                                    select client.Element("name").Value;
```

However, that only returns me the names, and I need all the data. Also, the number of addresses are variable.

Please edit the question and/or title as you see fit.Ignore any tipos, since i have translated this code from my native language.

Comment: First problem - you're using a range variable of `client` in your query, but you never use that in either the `where` or the `select`. Maybe that's a typo - it would be easier to tell if you could provide a [mcve]...

Comment: I think you meant to use "Adress", not "Adresses" in your `Descendants` call.  And `Attribute` instead of `Element` for Name.

Comment: `I have tryed this without success:`  Why don't you tell us what happened?  Did you get an exception?  Did you get the wrong data?

Comment: "The 'Name' start tag on line 3 position 6 does not match the end tag of 'Nome'. Line 3, position 24." : `<Name>Granicentro</Nome>`

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @meme your linq statement has `from client`, but in your where clause, you only reference `cliente2` and `cliente`.  That doesn't make very much sense in a where clause, because it is not dependent on `client`

Comment: >.> another tipo, sorry

Comment: How can you have a typo in a code example that you have tried out? Didn't your compiler complain?

Comment: @ths like i said, i translated this code from my native language (portuguese), that is why some variables dont mach

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize objects with the following syntax:

```
var address = new Adress(){port = 80}
```

That will create a new `Adress` and set it's `port` property to `80`.  It will leave all other properties as their default values.

With that knowledge in mind, you can write your linq like this

```
IEnumerable<Client> clients = 
    from client in XDocument.Load(@"D:\W\Clients.xml").Descendants("client")
    orderby client.Element("Id") descending
    select new Client()
    {
        ClientName = client.Element("name").Value,
        Adresses = client.[Insert code to select addresses here]
            .Select(address => new List<Adress>()
            {
                new Adress()
                {
                    AdressName = address.[insert code to get address name here]
                    Ip = address.[insert code to get ip here]
                    port = address.[insert code to get port here]
                }
            }
            .ToList()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos in your XML as well as malformed XML (`<port> is getting closed with </porta>`). Spelling errors ("Adress") is not an issue but I guess you want to fix that as well.

Given that above xml is fixed, simplest way to map into a class is to use XmlSerializer. Define your root node, along with proper Xml attributes in your class. Also, note that you have class properties that have case differences from your XML.

Following example is a quick test that I ran, which worked fine.

```
public class Client
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
}

public class Adress
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string AdressName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Ip")]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Port")]
    public int port { get; set; }
}

private void Test()
{
    var xml = @"<Clients>
<Client Id=""1"">
<Name>Granicentro</Name>
<Adresses>
<Adress Name=""5648"">
<Ip>111,111,111,111</Ip>
<Port>1111</Port>
</Adress>
<Adress Name=""2222"">
<Ip>222,222,222,222</Ip>
<Port>2222</Port>
</Adress>
<Adress Name=""3333"">
<Ip>333,333,333,333</Ip>
<Port>3333</Port>
</Adress>
</Adresses>
</Client>
</Clients>";

    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "Clients";
    xRoot.Namespace = "";
    xRoot.IsNullable = true;

    List<Client> clients;
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Client>), xRoot);
    using(StringReader r = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        clients = (List<Client>)ser.Deserialize(r);

    }
    //Clients collection now has your data.
}
```